# SQL SELECT different foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I need select in two tables the foreign key match each other, but I don't want repeat the sames foreign key.

I have these tables on database:

```
    |Photo| (0/*) --------- (1)|Advertisement|

    |Photo|
       -photo_id
       -url
       -advertisement_id

    |Advertisement|
       -advertisement_id
       ...
```

Data on database

```
    |Photo|
       photo_id | url | advertisement_id
           1    |  x  |        1
           2    |  x  |        1
           3    |  x  |        2
           4    |  x  |        3
```

I want this:

```
       ID   | URL  
       1    |  x
       2    |  x    -> It is anyone url   
       3    |  x
```

I try SQL below, but this repeat ID =(

```
    SELECT a.advertisement_id as ID, p.url as URL  
    FROM Advertisement a  
    RIGHT JOIN Photo p
    ON a.advertisement_id = p.advertisement_id
    LIMIT 6
```

Result:

```
    ID  |  URL  
    1   |   http://i0.statig.com.br/bancodeimagens/18/46/2h/18...
    2   |   http://www.yaves.es/images/Animales/Tiernos-Gatito...
    2   |   http://images.forwallpaper.com/files/thumbs/previe...
    10  |   http://www.petmag.com.br/img/gatos/racas/7892/euro...
    7   |   http://www.gmstatic.com/content/images/1369932859_...
    8   |   http://www.navegandonaweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2...
```

Anyone help me construct the sql query?

Comment: use distinct keyword with id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.advertisement_id as ID, p.url as URL  
FROM Advertisement a  
RIGHT JOIN Photo p
ON a.advertisement_id = p.advertisement_id
GROUP BY a.advertisement_id
ORDER BY p.photo_id ASC (or DESC ? )
LIMIT 6
```

OR

```
SELECT a.advertisement_id as ID, p.url as URL  
FROM Advertisement a,Photo p
WHERE a.advertisement_id = p.advertisement_id
GROUP BY a.advertisement_id
ORDER BY p.photo_id ASC (or DESC ? )
LIMIT 6
```